# Is Dropbox going to always resolve my symlinks?

Tags: dropbox, symbolic-link

I have one folder within my Dropbox directory, and a link to that folder, also in my Dropbox directory. I use the files within my Dropbox folder on a laptop and a desktop computer.

I thought that since both the symlink and the folder it points to are both within the Dropbox folder that they would operate as usual.

However, after I use the folders on one machine, when I return to the other, the symlink will be replaced with a copy of the contents of the folder it originally pointed to.

Dropbox is completely defeating the purpose of having a symlink. Is there a way I can force Dropbox to preserve the symbolic link relationship between the link and the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be answered definitively as Dropbox *might* change everything or nothing tomorrow. I am neither Dropbox or the omnipotent entity that drives them.

That said, symlink resolution is a *feature* that allows people to sync things that aren't actually within their dropbox folders. This is handy if you want to back something up without actually moving it. Given that's how it currently works and is how people are using it, I think it highly doubtful they'll change that behaviour...

Since writing this, I've found a dozen or so threads and questions around the internet that all seem to agree. [An answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/581489/30127) suggests selective syncing as a workaround.

Comment: This may have been correct in 2014, but it's not correct now.  Dropbox breaks symlinks (replacing them with actual files).  The answer you have linked is actually suggesting that you ignore symlinks by using selective sync, which would preserve the link but not update the file.  That seems a bit pointless.